# Is considered best practice to let the state to be an object instead of a string?

Tags: reactjs, object, react-hooks, state, jsx

My form only contains one input that will be used in other components. Is it considered best practice to let the state be an object with a descriptive key or is it fine to only have a string as the state?

```
export const App = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("")
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables

Answer (score 1):

A string is perfectly fine. Having the state with `useState` being a string (or a number, or a boolean, or some other non-object) is extraordinarily common.

The time when you *wouldn't* want to use a primitive for state is when you want to put multiple values in a single stateful variable, eg

```
const [name, setName] = useState({
  first: '',
  last: '',
});
```

(though, in that case above, you could use `firstName` and `setFirstName`, and `lastName` and `setLastName` instead, if you wanted.)

It'll depend on the circumstances. Sometimes having a primitive state makes the most sense. Sometimes using an object instead makes the code easier to manage.

Comment: I'm also thinking that an object would be better if I add a new input or something like that to the form?

Comment: I'm also wondering which one is better in terms of performance?

Comment: It might be, it might not. It depends on the situation. If you have, eg, 5+ inputs, using an object could well make state management easier. But if you only have two or three inputs, using separate states might be better - it's up to you, and on how you use the state elsewhere.

Comment: The performance impact of either method is utterly negligible. Write *clean, readable* code instead.

Comment: Which one would you use in my case?

Comment: Since you only have one stateful value, there's no point in having an object. A string is just fine.